# Is it still unit testing, when I write a WebInterface?

Tags: unit-testing

I have a more general question:
Assuming I have a web application, for example using the Struts2 Framework.
Therefore it becomes quite complicated to write Unit tests for functions, as you have to mock every aspect of the Framework.
The Database+Connection, The Session, a LDAP-Connection or what ever else is needed, which I do not have written on my own
It would be much easier to write the unit Tests so, that they run in a WebInterface inside the Base-Application, as all these things then already would exist.

### The question:

**Would you guys still consider this as unit testing?**

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts..

The question is very general. My suggestion is that you still want to write some sort of Unit Tests for number of reasons. Firstly you can run them as an automated test suite so if something breaks you know quickly. Secondly you get a better designed system - Your objects are loosely coupled. You get more confident on the code you write.

If you have a framework harder to test,

a. Try abstracting away some dependencies, so they code can be injected without interfering with real instances.
b. Use a testing framework that can break any tightly coupled harder dependencies.

Harder to provide a comprehensive answer, but this is the general direction, which I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider what you really want to test first. A framework, for its definition, will use the classes you provide to do some "magic". Do you want to test that has already been tested "magic" or the business core of the app you programmed?.

Also, something you should consider, is where to stop testing. You probably don't want to test the connection to the database (considering what you wrote) so just mock it.

Take in consideration that you will have to test just one functionality at the time, don't think of having, for example, the database connection and the ldap in the same test, it wouldn't be unit testing.

Take a look at this tutorial also :http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/index.html